# Etiquette: How to version control editor configuration without polluting upstream repository

Tags: git, github

When contributing to a GitHub project, I don't want to publish my personal editor (VSCode) settings, yet I'd still want to track them somehow.

Example: Visual Studio Code puts it's configuration in a `.vscode` directory.  If I ignore that (i.e. in my global `.gitignore`), I lose the ability to save these settings for later use.  If keep it, it shows up in any PR's I create.

A separate branch in my fork seems awkward.  Stashes don't push to GitHub.

Some settings are unique to a project and developer (insert Venn diagram here). How can I track them? I've searched SO and elsewhere but can't find an existing answer.

Comment: you may add `.vscode` to `.gitignore` in your public repository and then initiate a private repository inside `.vscode` so you can track changes inside this directory

Comment: Why do you want to track them? Do you want to be able to go back to an earlier version / see how they changed over time?

Comment: Say I'm working on a bugfix, and my debugger is configured to test for that bug.  I sometimes want to switch to another bugfix (different branch), with a different configuration.  These only of use to me.

Answer (score -2):

As you mentioned correctly Once you commit the file it will **begin to be tracked**.
In order to ignore the `.vscode` folder use `assume-unchanged`

---

You can still ignore added files with the `assume-unchanged` flag

> ***`--[no-]assume-unchanged`***
>
> When this flag is specified, the object names recorded for the paths are not updated.
>   Instead, this option sets/unsets the "assume unchanged" bit for the paths.
>
> When the `assume unchanged` bit is on, the user promises not to change the file and allows Git to assume that the working tree file matches what is recorded in the index.
>
> If you want to change the working tree file, you need to unset the bit to tell Git.
>
> Git will fail (gracefully) in case it needs to modify this file in the index e.g. when merging in a commit; thus, in case the assumed-untracked file is changed upstream, you will need to handle the situation manually.

---

Explaining how to do from the command line

```
# Remove the file from the repository if you have committed it already
# and you don't want to keep it
git rm --cached .vscode/

# now update your gitignore file to ignore this folder
echo '.vscode' >> .gitignore

# add the .gitignore file
git add .vscode

# ... git commit and push
```

From this point git **will** track changes to this folder, so now you have to "turn" on the assume unchanged so git will not detect your local changes.

- You can always turn it off and add your changes when you wish to do so

  [image]

Comment: The [Git documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/14c781fcd47c8d8b771cd189f43840f355b19512/Documentation/git-update-index.txt#L552-L567) explicitly documents that `--assume-unchanged` isn't supposed to be used for this.

Comment: There are lots of git commands which will undo `--assume-unchanged` -- it's an optimization, not a way of ignoring untracked changes

Comment: Besides, the question asks about tracking them (but not in the main repository). The OP already mentions they can ignore it with their global .gitignore (although .git/info/exclude would also work)